# Crop video scale square to round shape -Android

Tags: android, video, ffmpeg, crop

Currently I'm developing video editing app, in which i want to **overlay** video to image i used **FFMPEG** library and use overlay command  and export video to video.mp4 format

Here is done with overlay command :

```
private void extractImagesVideo() {
    File moviesDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
    Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES
);

String filePrefix = "extract_picture";
String fileExtn = ".mp4";

File dir = new File(moviesDir, "VideoEditor");
int fileNo = 0;
while (dir.exists()) {
fileNo++;
dir = new File(moviesDir, "VideoEditor" + fileNo);

}
dir.mkdir();
File dest = new File(dir, filePrefix + "%03d" + fileExtn);

Log.d(TAG, "startTrim: dest: " + dest.getAbsolutePath());

// String complexCommand[]={"-y","-i",mStrImagePath,"-i",mStrVideoPath,"-filter_complex","[0]scale=720:1280:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,drawbox=x=10:y=10:w=100:h=100:color=pink@0.5:t=max: (ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2,setsar=1[backd],[backd][1] overlay=x=(main_w-overlay_w)/(main_w-overlay_w):y=(main_h-overlay_h)","-acodec","copy",dest.getAbsolutePath()};

String complexCommand[]={"-y","-i",mStrVideoPath,"-f","lavfi","-i","color=c=black:s=1920x1080","-filter_complex","[0:v]scale=w=0.80*iw:h=0.80*ih[scaled],[1:v][scaled]overlay=x=0.10*main_w:y=0.10*main_h:eof_action=endall[out]","-acodec","copy",dest.getAbsolutePath()};


// String complexCommand[]={"-y","-i",mStrImagePath,"-i",mStrVideoPath,"-filter_complex","[1:v] scale=200:200 [ovr1], [1:v] scale=200:200 [ovrl2], [0:v][ovr1] overlay=25:25:enable='between(t,0,20)' [temp1], [temp1][ovrl2] overlay=50:50:enable='between(t,20,40)'","-acodec","copy",dest.getAbsolutePath()};
// String complexCommand[]={"-y","-i",mStrImagePath,"-i",mStrVideoPath,"-filter_complex","[0]scale=1024:1280:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1024:1280:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2,setsar=1[backd],[backd][1] overlay=x=(main_w-overlay_w)/(main_w-overlay_w):y=(main_h-overlay_h):shortest=1","-acodec","copy",dest.getAbsolutePath()};

/* Remove -r 1 if you want to extract all video frames as images from the specified time duration.*/
execFFmpegBinary(complexCommand);
}
```

Issue is video showing square shape i want to crop video into rounded shape, i check almost solutions and check also **FFMPEG** commands , i found mask overlay on video but isn't a proper solution

Comment: See https://superuser.com/q/1270950

Comment: Please check this and try with that filter https://superuser.com/a/1271022

Comment: Is this solved now? Or you still need solution but just not responding to the comments?